# Fragment Switching Crashes in Sliding Drawer if clicked any item twice?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been using a Sliding Drawer.Now I have options like Home and Friends etc.Now if i click the HomeFragment first it works nice and then click on FriendsFragment it also works nice.Now if i again click on HomeFragment again from sliding drawer it crashes.It gives below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #44: 

    Duplicate id 0x7f0a008c, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4722)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at com.example.MAPit.MAPit.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:54)
                at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
                at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have write below code to switch between fragments

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

Then i tried to do this code but got the same error of above mentioned.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment);
            transaction.commit();
```

Is there anything i have to do in oncreateView of the Fragments like I have this in HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private GoogleMap map;
    MapFragment mapFrag;
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_map_activity, null, false);

        mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mapFrag.getMap();
        //added the custom info adapter
        if (map != null) {
            map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    // creating my own info for latest frnd status
                    String status="Hi how are you everyone? Have a nice day ahead";
                    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_info_listview, null);
                    TextView tvFrndname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_frnd_name);
                    TextView tvFrndStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_frnd_status);
                    tvFrndname.setText("Neerob Basak"); // Later it will be name of friend
                    //checking for length of status
                    if(status.length()>10){
                        String substatus = status.substring(0,20);
                        substatus +="...";
                        tvFrndStatus.setText(substatus);
                    }
                    return v;
                }
            });
        }

       //onclick listener on marker of friends location

        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                Fragment fragment = new FriendsStatusFragment();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).commit();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Is there any check i have to give while i am clicking the same option in the sliding drawer which was previously clicked??

Comment: post your onCreateView method also.

Comment: You might consider disabling your button after the first click, and then when the fragment is finished, reenable it to prevent launching the same fragment twice.

Comment: why they gave me down vote i didn't understand.Did i ask any dumb question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your fragment Java file

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() 
         {
            super.onDestroyView(); 
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);  
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

And also add this

```
@Override
public void onPause() 
{
  super.onPause();
 if(map!=null)
     map=null;
}
```

Comment: can u explain what actually are u doing??

Comment: your code works..But can i get the previously done work in that fragment by switching that fragment??

Comment: Basically the map crashes for you when u click twice so what I am doing is whenever you are destroying the view or whenever you switch to another fragment I set the map fragment to be null so that it loads again. :)

Comment: why they gave me down vote i didn't understand.Did i ask any dumb question??

Comment: No even I faced this issue! :) it's not a dumb question we are learning so there is nothing wrong to help one another out

Comment: So why someone is just giving downvote and blocking me to post in stackoverflow for just the query of bad question.

Comment: But I am facing one problem when i am in HomeFragment where there is a map and clicking the Home Button again my app crashes.Can i disable that item of the listView so that i can't click on that again if am there in the HomeFragment??

Answer (score 1):

Fragment transactions do not happen immediately after you call commit().

You might consider disabling your button after the first click, and then when the fragment is finished, re-enable it to prevent launching the same fragment twice.  This is a method known as debouncing.

Another option would be to call fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions(); after your commit to cause it to process the transaction immediately.

Comment: Can't i check anything to get back the previous view of that fragment when i come back in the oncreateView of HomeFragment by clicking the Home button again???

Comment: this is a good answer, however the javadoc suggest using commitNow() instead of executePendingTransactions().